# Getting root directory name from a directory string - PHP

Tags: php

I have a variable like

`$dir = "dir1/dir2/dir3"`etc..etc..

I want to extract `dir1` from this string, which is the root directory name. How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove root directory from a directory path string - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696977/remove-root-directory-from-a-directory-path-string-php) - Please do not create pairing questions which are actually a duplicate. Also you are invited to use the search of this website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dirArr = explode('/', $dir);
$rootDir = $dirArr[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer would be to `$dirs = explode('/', $dir)` and then `array_shift($dirs)` but thats not as robust as it could be. Do you know where this is on your filesystem?  A better answer will reveal itself with more context...