# Remove root directory from a directory path string - PHP

Tags: php

I have a variable like `$path = "dir1/dir2/dir1/dir4/";` etc.. etc..

I want to remove the first member `dir1/` and want result like `dir2/dir1/dir4/`.

I think it is possible by making the variable an array by `explode('/', $path)`. How can I remove the first member vrom array and reconstruct that array into a text variable??

How can I achieve this in PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your updated question

Only explode into two parts, take the second one. In case the second one does not exists, give it `NULL`:

```
list(, $result) = explode("/", $path, 2) + array( 1 => NULL);
```

OR

```
$array = explode("/", $path);
unset($array[0]);
echo $text = implode("/", $array);
```

Comment: @blasteralfred why did you choose 3 lines over one simple line with regexp?

Comment: @meze: regexp are slow than these functions and you can also convert these three lines in one line of code

Comment: how do you know that regexp is slower than these lines? Regexp isn't always slow. In some cases regexp will be faster than those three lines. And you can't convert it into one line of code.

Comment: It's not "these three lines" anymore, it's different now ;) And it became slower than the regexp solution because internally it will create 2 arrays...

Comment: @meze: And do you know what preg_replace internally does? It is not recommended to use regex until you really need it.

Comment: `until you really need it` who said that? Regexp is a powerful tool for searching and replacing in texts. It is not recommended to use arrays to cut off a string. Btw, why did we forget about substr + strpos? Anyway, before making any assumptions about perfomance, take a profile and check the difference.

Comment: Without offensive language please. Here is my result: http://codepad.org/j7k1SJgx

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_replace('~^[^/]+/~', '', $path);
```

or if you don't want regexp:

```
substr($path, strpos($path, '/') + 1);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Not all researchers understand regex pattern syntax.  There should probably be a warning in this answer regarding the fact that you are not checking `strpos()` for `=== false`, and any passed in string without slashes will have unintended mutation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = explode("/", $path); // Pull it apart
array_shift($result); // Pop the first index off array
$result = implode("/", $result); // Put it together again
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that
$result= explode("/", $path);.
You will get result as an array.