# How can I insert symbol '+' after each char of a string?

Tags: php

How can I insert symbol '+' after each char of a string?

Like changing from `mystring` to `m+y+s+t+r+i+n+g+`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the 'website' or 'web' tags.

Comment: But the question stands on itself and has nothing to do with the website.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use this:

```
print implode("+", str_split($string));
```

To add one extra `+` after, just concatenate `. "+"`.

**Note:** this approach is fast enough for not very long strings. Another way is to use regular expressions as illustrated in [@zerkms answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796785/1249581).

Comment: @Jeroen: is "not using regex" a new trend? Let's not use string functions but allocate memory for another array. Cool!

Comment: Not at all, but it's significantly faster than using a regex (at least in this case)

Comment: @Jeroen: can you prove that? Especially "significantly" part

Comment: Your solution replaces even spaces

Comment: Regex fails here because you need to change every possible symbol.

Comment: @Donut - as asked in the question - every character is replaced. I think space is counted as a character.

Comment: @zerkms: Ran both 100.000 times, VisioNs method took 0.20612788200378 seconds, while Donuts method took 0.28263688087463 seconds

Comment: Ah I see now, regex is better with long strings, while str_split/implode is better with short ones

Comment: @Jeroen: correct. And for arbitrary input regexes are better: they don't lose a lot on small strings, consume **less** memory and win on long strings. So I hope you won't underestimate regexes next time :-)

Comment: I have two version implode(); and preg_replace(); does implode is better than preg_replace?

Comment: @Eveler, they both do the job fine.

Comment: jeroen tested seems your option faster:)

Comment: @Eveler, slightly for not very long strings.

Comment: @zerkms lol same story in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9696977/265712).

Comment: @VisioN I'm against converting to arrays when you work with strings. It can't be faster than regexp that are made to work with strings. I'm not against non-regex solutions, if you had suggested `echo wordwrap($text, 1, "+", true);`, I'd upvote you ;p

Comment: @meze Fine. So you blame using arrays because of the speed (and memory usage?). But did I ever say that my solution is the best? It was another way to solve the problem. And it works. It works fine, doesn't it? For the current string this solution works even faster than with regex (the guys had long discussion about that above). Of course, it's your decision but I reckon you are not *correct*.

Comment: @VisioN: just to be clear - I didn't downvote you. I upvoted your answer yesterday when it had +1

Comment: @zerkms I know that. Thanks. That's not a problem in reputation or whatever, I simply can't get what makes people to behave like that. I can downvote someone if the answer absolutely does not suit the question; if the answer has serious problems in syntax and it shows incompetence of the answerer... but here! Following same logic, I can downvote to every answer *"because I'm against doing something"* :/

Comment: @VisioN I downvote because I'm against using the array-hammer when you need to alter a string. Make an edit to your post, I'll change it to upvote - there was a little confusion with Jeroen ;)

Comment: @meze You'd better submit your `wordwrap` solution. It seems to be both fast and short. Possibly it is even better than all others.

Comment: This sure has been going on for very long. Please take this to chat.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = 'string';

echo preg_replace('~.~', '\\0+', $str);
```

Comment: +1 for regex solution. In fact, I haven't thought about the speed, just that usual 'JavaScript style' did my thinking :)

Comment: @VisioN: I would use `str.replace` for js as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$text = 'mystring';

// To match only characters (no numbers):
$replaced = preg_replace("/([a-z])/i", "$1+", $text);

// To match both
$replaced = preg_replace("/([a-z0-9])/i", "$1+", $text);
```

Comment: @Eveler Yes if you replace `[a-z]` with `.`.