# Remove All chars except from a given list in PHP

Tags: php

I've been racking my brain and scavenging the internet for over an hour now...

Im looking for a function in PHP simular to "trim" but one that removes any character except those in a given list, for example;

```
$niceChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_+";
$rawString = "myString";
$happyString = removeNastyNess($rawString, $niceChars);
```

Does any such function exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reg exp:

```
function removeNastyNess($rawString, $niceChars) {
    return implode('', array_intersect(str_split($rawString), str_split($niceChars)));
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about that, but it will grab excessive piece of memory.

Comment: We had long discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10796789/1249581) about that. Seems that on long `$rawString`s regexp use much less memory and execution time.

Comment: @VisioN thanks for sharing. But, don't program for the CPU - program for the programmer after you... I can do reg exps, but normally you don't see what they are doing. Some lines of program code are always easier to read...

Comment: If this were to be implemented on a large scale I would go with the reg exp, but my system is for a small base of admins creating pages. So Im going with powtac, but making note of the others for the future, thanks powtac.

Comment: _“But, don't program for the CPU - program for the programmer after you...”_ – I don’t think you’re doing them a favor with that code snippet you posted. I think a clean little RegEx is much easier to understand here. (Supposing the programmer after you knows some basic RegEx – which he should.)

Comment: Well, as long as in one’s real code one _comments_ what one’s doing, I see no problem with using your version either :-)

Comment: @CBroe In my opinion comments are only necessary when code is not readable on the fist view... The goal should always be to write beautiful code. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php). Your nice character set looks like `[\w-+]` rule. So, the solution could be as follows.

```
$happyString = preg_replace("/[^\w-+]/", "", $rawString);
```

Comment: '\w' includes all alpha (letters and digits) as well as the underscore, so [^\w-+] will work fine

Comment: @Sp4cecat Underscore is included to `\w`.

Comment: Yup Vis, it also includes numbers.

Comment: @Sp4cecat Right, I forgot about that :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace("|[^abcdef]|", '')`? (where abcdef are the characters to allow)

Comment: For the regular expression use `[^a-zA-Z0-9\-+_]`